# How do I get unique records by comparing the first n characters?

Tags: javascript

How do I get every single record of an array string substring?

Example:

```js
sourcefiles = ['a.pdf', 'a_ok.pdf', 'a.csv', 'b_ok.csv', 'b.csv', 'c.pdf']
var uniq = [ ...new Set(sourcefiles)];   //I want the output to be: a, b, c
console.log(uniq)
```

I tried to add substring:

```js
sourcefiles = ['a.pdf', 'a_ok.pdf', 'a.csv', 'b_ok.csv', 'b.csv', 'c.pdf']
var uniq = [ ...new Set(sourcefiles.substring(0,1))]; 
console.log(uniq)
```

```
VM116792:2 Uncaught TypeError: sourcefiles.substring is not a function
    at <anonymous>:2:37
```

How do I get unique records by comparing the first n characters?

Comment: you can't call substring method on an array of strings, you should iterate over it and call ti on individual elements

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Iterating over Arrays in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33750626/iterating-over-arrays-in-javascript)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were close! You just had to use `map()` to get the substrings, as the array class has no `subString()` method:

```js
const sourcefiles = ['a.pdf', 'a_ok.pdf', 'a.csv', 'b_ok.csv', 'b.csv', 'c.pdf'];
const uniq = [...new Set(sourcefiles.map(a => a.substring(0,1)))] 
console.log(uniq);
```

As noted elsewhere, shorter isn't necessarily better. `reduce()` outperforms creating a new Set. Here it is in one (crammed) line:

```
const uniq = sourcefiles.reduce((a,s) => { a.includes(s[0]) ? null : a.push(s[0]); return a}, []);
```

Comment: It looks nicer but is measurably slower, just fair warning. `reduce()` will outperform it, as others have noted.

Comment: @randy-casburn offers an answer that performs more optimally and can be crammed into a one liner if you want performance and concision: `const uniq = sourcefiles.reduce((a, n) => a.includes(n[0]) ? null : a.push(n[0]), [])`

Answer (score 1):

```js
const sourcefiles = ['a.pdf', 'a_ok.pdf', 'a.csv', 'b_ok.csv', 'b.csv', 'c.pdf']
var arr = [ ...sourcefiles].map(i=> i.substring(0,1));
var uniq = [ ...new Set(arr)];

console.log(uniq)
```

Answer (score 1):

Reduce might work faster than map and Set

```js
sourcefiles = ['a.pdf', 'a_ok.pdf', 'a.csv', 'b_ok.csv', 'b.csv', 'c.pdf']
var uniq = sourcefiles.reduce((acc, cur) => {
  const firstChar = cur.substring(0, 1);
  if (!acc.find(fn => fn.substring(0, 1) === firstChar)) acc.push(cur)
  return acc
}, [])
console.log(uniq)
```

If you only want the first char then

```js
sourcefiles = ['a.pdf', 'a_ok.pdf', 'a.csv', 'b_ok.csv', 'b.csv', 'c.pdf']
var uniq = sourcefiles.reduce((acc, cur) => {
  const firstChar = cur.substring(0, 1);
  if (!acc.includes(firstChar)) acc.push(firstChar)
  return acc
}, [])
console.log(uniq)
```

Comment: is there any way for me to know if this is going to be faster than the map?

Comment: Sure. Run jsperf on them

Answer (score 1):

Another, simpler take on reduce: (based upon code comment in OPS code: *//I want the output to be: a, b, c*)

```js
sourcefiles = ['a.pdf', 'a_ok.pdf', 'a.csv', 'b_ok.csv', 'b.csv', 'c.pdf'];
const out = sourcefiles
  .reduce(
    (acc, n) => {
      acc.includes(n[0]) ? null : acc.push(n[0]); // no-op if found in array
      return acc;
    }, []);
console.log(out);
```

Comment: I think a simple if is easier on the eye than using a side-effect in a ternary that you feel the need to explain in a comment - see [my second example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64592138/295783)

Comment: @mplungjan - you produce the same side effect by returning rather than mutating `acc` - not a lot of difference, but readability is clear. Both work effectively well.

Comment: I mean the side effect of executing code in a ternary to set the value in what is tested in the ternary.

Comment: Yes, the if statement is better - if you provided that feedback in a code review I would certainly refactor this. On the other hand, not all side effects are disasters - this code is completely isolated.

Answer (score 1):

```js
const sourcefiles = ['a.pdf', 'a_ok.pdf', 'a.csv', 'b_ok.csv', 'b.csv', 'c.pdf']    
const result = sourcefiles.map(singleSourceFile => singleSourceFile.substring(0,1)).filter((v, i, a) => a.indexOf(v) === i);

console.log(result);
```

One can use substring with 'n' characters defined as a second arg and find unique elements using `filter` method available in conjunction with `indexOf`.